# How to send parameters to daemon from client to server?

Tags: daemon, kiosk

I am trying to create a kiosk client that stores its configuration on the server. Client is based on Raspberry Pi OS Lite (it runs on RevPi). Server is an Debian system. What I had in mind is following process:

- boot kiosk (first boot with customized Raspberry Pi OS Lite)
- kiosk will ask for server IP (maunual input)
- kiosk will create ssh key at this moment
- kiosk will ask server at given IP for registration (passing its MAC and generated key?)
- **? Server will receive request from kiosk with MAC and generated key.**
- server will create config file for that MAC address (copy from template) and do some more adminitrative tasks.
- kiosk will reboot
- after boot kiosk will check if his local config file is same as version on the server
- if not: kiosk will download it AND reboot.
- if yes: it will precess it and run... for ever till end of electricity.

I am done with cleaning up kiosk, I have installed what I need, all is configured as I wanted.
Now I am looking for an elegant solution to my only problem, atm:
How to send kiosks MAC address to server without any login ceremony. I thought of using a daemon on server side that listens at port for and messages with MAC address and ssh-keys but it have no idea how to

I used info from [how to pass arguments to Linux daemon/service](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11335860/13434289) and my daemon is based on http://www.netzmafia.de/skripten/unix/linux-daemon-howto.html

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after looking around I found [spring-server](https://github.com/bartobri/spring-server/tree/e536a67e2012e7e8b07c6efd1f235e83b1707bcd). This is much more then I anticipated for! But all additional functionality offers more application possibilities! Thank You [Bartobri](https://github.com/bartobri).
With implementation of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40182414/13434289) answer I am good to go.